# python: convert list into binary decision based on a condition

Tags: python

Is there a non-verbose way to convert list into binary decision based on a condition? e.g.:

```
patientAge = [19, 15, 13, 21, 37]

# wanted output: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1] # true if >18 otherwise false
# e.g. in matlab simply "patientAge>18"
```

Comment: `(np.array(patientAge) > 18).astype(int)` if you use `numpy`.

Comment: Try: `mean(filter(lambda x: x > 18, patientAge))` Also, there's no point nitpicking and comparing languages. For every thing matlab is better at, there are 10 things python is better at.

Comment: That doesn't work for the real data I work on as I have to get the indices of one array based on a condition and select the corresponding indices from another one: Matlab semantic of "mean(score(patientAge>18))"? i.e. the mean score of everyone over 18?
patientAge = [19, 15, 13, 21, 37]
score = [123, 213, 429, 98, 50]

patientAge = np.array(patientAge)
score = np.array(score)
idx = (patientAge > 18)
print(idx)
print(np.mean(score(idx))) # TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: `score[idx]` indexing with square brackets... not round

Comment: Thanks with patientAge = [ 19,  15,  13, 21, 37]
score =      [123, 213, 429, 98, 50]
patientAge = np.array(patientAge)
score = np.array(score)
print(np.mean(score[patientAge > 18])) it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> patientAge = [19, 15, 13, 21, 37]
>>> [age > 18 for age in patientAge]
[True, False, False, True, True]
```

and if you must have 1 or 0:

```
>>> [int(age > 18) for age in patientAge]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Comprehension: `[ v > 18 for v in patientAge ]`
- If using numpy (assuming `patientAge` is a `numpy.array`) you can also write `patientAge > 18` and obtain a bool `numpy.array`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the list into a `numpy` array:

```
>>> patientAge = [19, 15, 13, 21, 37]
>>> patientAge = numpy.array(patientAge)
>>> patientAge>18
array([ True, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> _+0             # if you want ints
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

The syntax is familiar because `numpy` (and `matplotlib`) are of course based on Matlab.